# Smoothing / interpolating categorical data (fast)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, iteration

I am currently working with an array, containing categorical data.
Categories are organised like this: None,zoneA, zoneB
My array is a measure of sensors, it tells me if, at any time, the sensor is in zoneA, zoneB or not in a zone.

My goal here is to smooth those values.

For example, the sensor could be out of zoneA or b for a period of 30 measures, but if it happened I want those measures to be "smoothed".

Ex :

> array[zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, None, None, zoneA, zoneA, None, None, None, zoneA]

should give

> array[zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, zoneA, None, None, None, zoneA]

with a threshold of 2.

Currently, I am using an iteration over arrays, but its computation is too expensive and can lead to 1 or 2 min of computation. Is there an existing algorithm to answer that problem?

My current code :

```
 def smooth(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): dataframe with landlot column to smooth.
    Returns:dataframe smoothed
    """
    df_iter = df
    last = "None"
    last_index = 0
    for num, line in df_iter.iterrows():
        if (
                (line.landlot != "None")
                and (line.landlot == last)
                and (num - last_index <= self.delay)
                and (
                df_iter.iloc[(num - 1), df_iter.columns.get_loc("landlot")]
                == "None"
        )
        ):
            df_iter.iloc[
            last_index: (num + 1),  # noqa: E203
            df_iter.columns.get_loc("landlot"),
            ] = last
        if line.landlot != "None":
            last = line.landlot
            last_index = num
    return df_iter
```

Comment: What should `[zoneA, None, zoneB]` become?

Comment: Hello @timgeb, it should stay [zoneA, None, zoneB], smoothing only happen between two equals measure.

Comment: Why is `[zoneA, None, None, zoneA]` smoothed but `[zoneA, None, None, None, zoneA]` is not? edit: ah, that's what you mean by threshold of 2?

Comment: @timgeb threshold is the max "distance" or records between two measure of same zone to smooth on. If distance is more than threshold, no smoothing should be made.

Comment: Can you show an example fo your current code?

Comment: To help you improve your code, we need to see it. Either to optimize it or to compare its speed with other algorithms.

Comment: @EdgarH I just edit my post and had it. Landlots are the "zones"

Answer (score 1):

### Python implementation

I like to start these kind of things clean and simple. Therefore I just wrote a simple class that does exactly what is needed, without thinking too much about optimization. I call it `Interpolator` as this looks like categorical interpolation to me.

```py
class Interpolator:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.current_idx = 0
        self.current_nan_region_start = None
        self.result = None
        self.maxgap = 1

    def run(self, maxgap=2):
        # Initialization
        self.result = [None] * len(self.data)
        self.maxgap = maxgap
        self.current_nan_region_start = None
        prev_isnan = 0

        for idx, item in enumerate(self.data):
            isnan = item is None
            self.current_idx = idx
            if isnan:
                if prev_isnan:
                    # Result is already filled with empty data.
                    # Do nothing.
                    continue
                else:
                    self.entered_nan_region()
                    prev_isnan = 1
            else:  # not nan
                if prev_isnan:
                    self.exited_nan_region()
                    prev_isnan = 0
                else:
                    self.continuing_in_categorical_region()

    def entered_nan_region(self):
        self.current_nan_region_start = self.current_idx

    def continuing_in_categorical_region(self):
        self.result[self.current_idx] = self.data[self.current_idx]

    def exited_nan_region(self):

        nan_region_end = self.current_idx - 1
        nan_region_length = nan_region_end - self.current_nan_region_start + 1

        # Always copy the empty region endpoint even if gap is not filled
        self.result[self.current_idx] = self.data[self.current_idx]

        if nan_region_length > self.maxgap:
            # Do not interpolate as exceeding maxgap
            return

        if self.current_nan_region_start == 0:
            # Special case. data starts with "None"
            # ->  Cannot interpolate
            return

        if self.data[self.current_nan_region_start - 1] != self.data[self.current_idx]:
            # Do not fill as both ends of missing data
            # region do not have same value
            return

        # Fill the gap
        for idx in range(self.current_nan_region_start, self.current_idx):
            self.result[idx] = self.data[self.current_idx]


def interpolate(data, maxgap=2):
    """
    Interpolate categorical variables over missing
    values (None's).

    Parameters
    ----------
    data: list of objects
        The data to interpolate. Holds
        categorical data, such as 'cat', 'dog'
        or 108. None is handled as missing data.
    maxgap: int
        The maximum gap to interpolate over.
        For example, with maxgap=2, ['car', None,
        None, 'car', None, None, None, 'car']
        would become  ['car', 'car', 'car' 'car',
        None, None None, 'car'].

    Note: Interpolation will only occur on missing
    data regions where both ends contain the same value.
    For example, [1, None, 2, None, 2] will become
    [1, None, 2, 2, 2].
    """

    interpolator = Interpolator(data)
    interpolator.run(maxgap=maxgap)
    return interpolator.result
```

This is how one would use it (code for `get_data()` below):

```py
data = get_data(k=100)
interpolated_data = interpolate(data)
```

### Copy-paste Cython implementation

Most probably the python implementation is fast enough, as with array size of 1000.000, the amount of time needed to process the data is 0.504 seconds on my laptop. Anyway, [creating Cython versions](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) is fun and might give small additional timing bonus.

**Needed steps:**

- Copy-paste the python implementation into new file, called `fast_categorical_interpolate.pyx`
- Create `setup.py` to the same folder, with following contents:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        "fast_categorical_interpolate.pyx",
        language_level="3",
    ),
)
```

- Run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to build the Cython extension. You'll see something like `fast_categorical_interpolate.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` in the same folder.
- Now, you may use the interpolator like this:

```py
import fast_categorical_interpolate as fpi
data = get_data(k=100)
interpolated_data = fpi.interpolate(data)
```

- Of course, there might be some optimizations that you could do in the Cython code to make this even faster, but on my machine the speed improvement was 38% out of the box with N=1000.000 and 126% when N=10.000.

### Timings on my machine

- When N=100 (number of items in the list), python implementation is about 160x , and Cython implementation about 250x faster than `smooth`

```
In [8]: timeit smooth(test_df, delay=2)
10.2 ms ± 669 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [9]: timeit interpolate(data)

64.8 µs ± 7.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [10]: timeit fpi.interpolate(data)
41.3 µs ± 4.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

- When N=10.000, the timing difference is about 190x (Python) to 302x (Cython).

```
In [5]: timeit smooth(test_df, delay=2)
1.08 s ± 166 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [6]: timeit interpolate(data)
5.69 ms ± 852 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [7]: timeit fpi.interpolate(data)
3.57 ms ± 377 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

- When N=1000.000, the python implementation is about 210x faster and Cython implementation is about 287x faster.

```
In [9]: timeit smooth(test_df, delay=2)
1min 45s ± 24.2 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [10]: timeit interpolate(data)
504 ms ± 67.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [11]: timeit fpi.interpolate(data)
365 ms ± 38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## Appendix

### Test data creator `get_data()`

```py
import random
random.seed(0)

def get_data(k=100):
    return random.choices(population=[None, "ZoneA", "ZoneB"], weights=[4, 3, 2], k=k)
```

### Function and test data for testing `smooth()`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = get_data(k=1000)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(landlot=data)).fillna("None")


def smooth(df: pd.DataFrame, delay=2) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): dataframe with landlot column to smooth.
    Returns:dataframe smoothed
    """
    df_iter = df
    last = "None"
    last_index = 0
    for num, line in df_iter.iterrows():
        if (
            (line.landlot != "None")
            and (line.landlot == last)
            and (num - last_index <= delay)
            and (df_iter.iloc[(num - 1), df_iter.columns.get_loc("landlot")] == "None")
        ):
            df_iter.iloc[
                last_index : (num + 1),  # noqa: E203
                df_iter.columns.get_loc("landlot"),
            ] = last
        if line.landlot != "None":
            last = line.landlot
            last_index = num
    return df_iter
```

### Note on the "current code"

I think there must be some copy-paste error somewhere, as the "current code" does not work as all. I replaced the `self.delay` with a `delay=2` keyword argument to indicate the max gap. I assume that is was it was supposed to be.  Even with that the logic did not work correcly with the simple example data you provided.